# Using a dynamic name for image source in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have some decks of cards.
I want to display a specific image for each deck, I have an assets folder with all my images.

```
<div class="decks">

  <div *ngFor="let deck of decks" class="deck">

    <img
    src="../../assets/img/MAGE.png"
```

MAGE is just an exemple of a deckClass, that name should match deck.deckClass

```
  class="img-responsive"
  style="height: 200px;">

  <h4> {{deck.deckName}} : {{deck.deckClass}} </h4>
  <p *ngFor="let card of deck.deckCards" >
    {{ card.name }} : {{ card.manaCost }}
  </p>

</div>
</div>
```

How can I concatenate in a src attribute the deck.deckClass name in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Expression Context](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context)

You can wrap the sry attribute with square brackets, this way Angular will know to evaluate the value:

```
[src]="'../../assets/img/' + deck.deckClass '.png'"
```

See a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ua9cfc
I don't have images in there, so they will be shown as broken img's in the demo ...

p.s.: if those images are in your `src/assets/` folder, then this should suffice:

```
[src]="'assets/img/' + deck.deckClass '.png'"
```